# How to perform post install codesign in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, codesign

I have a simple C++ application built using CMake. In macOS it can be allowed to dump core on crash by doing something like:

```
 add_custom_command(TARGET mytarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :com.apple.security.get-task-allow bool true" coredump.entitlements
    COMMAND codesign -s - -f --entitlements coredump.entitlements $<TARGET_FILE:mytarget>
    COMMAND rm -f coredump.entitlements
    VERBATIM)
```

This works for the built program (e.g. running as `./build/bin/mytarget`) but after `make install` the installed program fails to start, error: `Killed: 9`

How can I perform the codesign step again after CMake install, or make the initial signing persistent through a `make install`?

Comment: `install(CODE ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Osyotr for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up with the following:

```
set(ENTITLEMENTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mytarget.entitlements")
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND
   codesign -s - -f --entitlements \"${ENTITLEMENTS}\" \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/mytarget\"
   )" COMPONENT Runtime)
```